Can't create local Git for project - class library's Git is used?
I created a ClassLibrary and created a local Git from the Git menu...

Then I created a WinForm project and added the ClassLibrary (add project)...

But now if I try to create a local Git for my WinForm project, then it is already using the ClassLibrary's local Git...

How can I tell Visual Studio 2022 that I want to create a new local Git for the WinForm project?
Thanks
UPDATE - folder structure:

ClassLibrary structure:

WinForm structure:


We can't tell what your folder structure looks like. It would be helpful to see that, including an indication of where the .git folder is (as that indicates the root of the git repo). Do you definitely need two different git repos at all? (Where possible, I try to keep everything that naturally fits within one solution in the same git repo. It makes it much easier to keep track of changes.)

@JonSkeet ... Thanks - I updated my post with the folder structure. In my real world projects, the ClassLibrary is a shared library in all my projects. And since the ClassLibrary is outside my projects, it is not includet in the Git changes.

What happens if you just run git init within the WinFormsApp1 directory (the one containing WinFormsApp1.sln)? I'm not familiar with the granularity of VS's git support, but I'd strongly recommend that you make sure you've at least got the git command line tool available, even if you only need it occasionally.
